# event.preventdefault not working in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a script that checks for a html5 local storage cookie and launches a modal window automatically if there is no cookie set.  It's for a language selector, once a language is selected then the user will stay on the page (EN) or redirected to the french site (FR).

Problem is that it doesn't work in firefox.  Actually the modal window (reveal.js) doesn't work at all.  Keep on getting the event.preventdefault error.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function langCheck(){
    var LS = localStorage.getItem('lang');
    if (LS == null) {
      $('#popup').click()
    } else if (LS == "FR") {
      alert("This is French")
      /* window.location.replace("http://www.supermarchepa.com/fr/index.html"); */
    }
  }
  function setToEng(){
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'EN');
    $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close')
  }
  function setToFr(){
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'FR')
  }
  window.onload = langCheck;
</script>
```

The modal window shows up automatically (on first visit) or the user can set the language by themselves using:

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade" data-closeonbackgroundclick="false" data-animationspeed="300" id="popup">Select Language</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And where is this `preventDefault()` ? Anyway, in IE and Chrome the `event` object is global, in Firefox you have to pass it as an argument, and that is most likely the issue, but looking at the code it's not immediately apparent where it should be passed, or where it's used ?

Comment: sorry, the error is pointing to the plugin file (reveal.js). here is a snippet of code in that file.                                                   (function ($) {
  $(document).on("click", 'a[data-reveal-id]', function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#' + modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) { 
    $(document).on("click", 'a[data-reveal-id]', function (e) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id'); 
        $('#' + modalLocation).reveal($(this).data()); 
    });
    // Im guessing more is comming here???
```

Anyway.. look at the first argument in your callback `function( e ) {` <-

```
// change: 
event.preventDefault();
// to:
e.preventDefault();
```

or change the argument name to `event`: `function( event )` <-